# Does somebody know the source of this hadith?

Tags: hadith, source-identification

I have a hadith of Prophet Muhammad (S.A.W) which states:

> Abu Hurayra reported that the Prophet (peace be upon him) said: “whoever, on the night preceding Friday, prays two rak’at, and in each rak’a recites (after the Fatiha) Ayat al Kursi once and surat al Ikhlas 15 times, and then after that salat, sits and says 1000 times, “Allahumma Salli ala Sayyidina Muhammadin an Nabiyy al Ummiyy” then he will see me in his sleep, and the next Friday will not come without him seeing me. And whoever sees me, then the Garden is his, and all his sins – past and future – are forgiven.”

I am clueless about the source of this hadith so can someone provide it to me?

Comment: I think this is a fabrication attributed to abu Hurayrah as if it was "that simple" everybody could see the Prophet and abu Hurayrah himself narrated a hadith http://sunnah.com/bukhari/91/12 on the matter making clear that it is not as easy. Also the version or expression of Greetings sent to the Prophet was not known until at the time of the Prophet nor the time of the early Muslim generation so it could be considered an inovation!

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide a source where you found this. As I found several parts but not this text!

Answer (score 1):

it's in a book called "Al-Ghoonya" attributed to Abdul Qadir al-Jilani.